# How to convert multiple if else in SWITCH case

Tags: php

Here i am using multiple if else how to convert it in switch case.

```
if($ridestatus == 'Y' && $pass_status == 'Y'){
    $status = '1';
}elseif($ridestatus == 'Y' && $pass_status == 'RNS'){
    $status = 'RNS';
}elseif($ridestatus == 'RNS' && $pass_status == 'Y'){
    $status = 'RNS';
}elseif($ridestatus == 'RNS' && $pass_status == 'RNS'){
    $status = 'RNS';
}elseif($ridestatus == 'Y' && $pass_status == 'NR'){
    $status = '1';
}elseif($ridestatus == 'RNS' && $pass_status == 'NR'){
    $status = 'RNS';
}elseif($ridestatus == 'NR' && $pass_status == 'Y'){
    $status = '1';
}elseif($ridestatus == 'NR' && $pass_status == 'RNS'){
    $status = 'RNS';
}elseif($ridestatus == 'NR' || $ridestatus == '' && $pass_status == 'NR' || $pass_status == ''){
    $status = '';
}
```

Comment: check the manual for [switch](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.switch.php) in PHP. you won't find anybody who will do the work for you

Comment: Is the question "How to make a switch?" or the problem is because you have to test two variables at same time?

Comment: `php` and `switch` thats it :P

Comment: if else is enough for this

Comment: Problem is because i am using two test condition's Here.@DavidLevel

Comment: @Abhishek_YII Technically: `switch (true) { case ($ridestatus == 'Y' && $pass_status == 'Y'):$status = '1';break; case (condition2):do stuff; break; ... }` will work. But it's ugly as hell.

Comment: @PLB it's beautiful by comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no need to convert it into `switch case`, **but** you can simplify it like,

```
<?php
    if($ridestatus == 'Y')
    {
        if($pass_status == 'Y' || $pass_status == 'NR')
            $status = '1';
        elseif($pass_status == 'RNS')
            $status = 'RNS';    
    }
    elseif($ridestatus == 'RNS')
    {
        if($pass_status!='')
            $status = 'RNS';
    }
    elseif($ridestatus == 'NR')
    {
        if($pass_status=='Y')
            $status = '1';
        elseif($pass_status == 'RNS')
            $status = 'RNS';
    }
    else
    {
        $status = '';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting tied up in the mechanics and loosing the logic.

This should be an equivalent test

```
if ($pass_status == 'RNS' || $ridestatus == 'RNS'){
    $status = 'RNS';
} elseif ($pass_status =='Y' || $ridestatus == 'Y'){
    $status = 1;
} else {
    $status = ''; 
}
```