# Pushing multiple Statements through a single channel of a Mux | if to case conversion

Tags: case, vhdl

I found a closed bad [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740826/how-to-convert-multiple-if-else-in-switch-case) through the forum search, so I'll try to make a better one, useful for anyone with the same Problem.

I am pretty new into VHDL. Till now I only worked with XILINX System Generator to program FPGA, which is nicely simple, but is not really something for my taste of coding. I work with a dS5203 FPGA board (feel free to search for the datasheet, stack overflow wont let me link it..). All my information regarding VHDL is learned in self-tuition, so feel free to correct any basic mistakes I made. I'll try to update this question as often as possible to create a useful question out of this.

**Please read the whole text before answering on any of my questions, since there are some mistakes I added intentional to get a concrete answer out of this.**

My Task is it to convert so if else code from C to VHDL. I could simply do that and if im not wrong the part of the code should look like this:

```
V1 : process
begin                 -- code will be marked in the Graph's as:
 if (a<=b) then       -- seq1
  var1 <= nr1;
  var2 <= nr2;
 elsif (c<=d) then     -- seq2
   var1 <= nr3;
   var2 <= nr4;
   var3 <= nr5;
  elsif (d<=f) then   -- seq3
    var2 <= nr6;
    var3 <= nr7;
   else           -- seq4
    var3 <= nr8;
   end if;
  end if;
 end if;
end process V1;
```

All variables (var 1-x, nr1-x are the same type)
:
If I'm not totally wrong, the resulting Hardware should look somehow like this
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt0tS.jpg)

As result there is a delay of 1 per "if .. then" (the real function contains more than 15 *if then else* commands).

First "sub questions":

*1: Does the "multiple statements in a single if .. then" thing work? Since I think I know how mux' work, I don't think that it's possible to punch multiple commands through one.*

*2: Does the "ignoring" of some variables (seq1 i.e. ignores var3) create "latch behavior"? I want to keep the old values in that variable and I think this way that should happen.*

To eliminate the delay I thought of the following attempt to transform it into a case... is:

```
variable sel : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);  --selector variable to steer mux behavior

S1: process(a,b)
begin
 if a <= b then
  sel(2) <= 1;
 else 
  sel(0) <= 0;
 endif;
end process S1;

S2: process(c,d)
begin
 if c <= d then
  sel(1) <= 1;
 else 
  sel(1) <= 0;
 endif;
end process S2;

S3: process(e,f)
begin
 if e <= f then
  sel(2) <= 1;
 else
  sel(2) <= 0;
 endif;
end process S3;

C1 : process (sel)
begin
case sel is
 when "000" 
  var3 <= nr8;
 when "001"
   var2 <= nr6;
   var3 <= nr7;
 when "010" | "011" 
  var1 <= nr3;
  var2 <= nr4;
  var3 <= nr5;
 when "100" | "101" | "111" | "110" 
  var1 <= nr1;
  var2 <= nr2;
end case;
end process C1;
```

Again the result should look somehow like this:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvMlr.jpg)

This way, I always will have a delay of 2, no matter how many if/else criteria I add. It will only add bits to the sel-variable. (And create a lot of code, but I prefer Performance/lower delay)

Some more "sub questions":

*3: is there a way to directly use <= ? because it's used as the "write to" command I tried to workaround by "if then else". Any simpler way?*

*4: Do I have to add a sort of delay? Since the first stage is a <= Operator a delay of 1 will be created*

These are all questions wich I will sooner or later be able to answer by myself. Feel free to answer or give hints ;) The real question wich bought me here:

**How can I get multiple Statements pushed through single channels of that giant mux?** (basically) the same question like question no. 1). As commented in the code I want to push multiple different variables/signals per if.. then. But a BUS-Signal wont work since there are differing amounts of satements.
I can not imagine that this somehow will work and have no idea how to workaround this problem. Do I think in the wrong way?

As a rookie Im excited to read your answers!
Greetings from Germany.

Edit: below again the same function with incorporated code of user1155120

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- a giant THANK YOU! to user1155120
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ifcase is -- ports
    port (
        in1:   in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);      -- 16 bit to get precise real type values
        in2:   in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0); 
        in3:   in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        in4:   in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        in5:   in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        in6:   in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        in7:   in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        in8:   in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);

        a:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);              -- arbitrary 8 bit size
        b:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        c:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        d:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        e:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        f:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);

        out1: out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);   -- DS5203 needs std_logic or std_logic vector
        out2: out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        out3: out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of ifcase is
    variable nr1: real (15 downto 0);                   -- not shure if I have or have not to add the (15 downto 0) for real values.
    variable nr2: real (15 downto 0);
    variable nr3: real (15 downto 0);
    variable nr4: real (15 downto 0);
    variable nr5: real (15 downto 0);
    variable nr6: real (15 downto 0);
    variable nr7: real (15 downto 0);
    variable nr8: real (15 downto 0);


    signal var1:    real (15 downto 0);
    signal var2:    real (15 downto 0);
    signal var3:    real (15 downto 0);



    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;

begin

typecon_fwd:
    process (in1, in2, in3,  in4, in5, in6, in7, in8)
    begin
    nr1 <= REAL(CONV_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(in1)))/65535.0;   -- x/(2^16 -1) = x/(65535) represents 16 bit real type number between 1 and 0(if i'm not wrong)
    nr2 <= REAL(CONV_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(in2)))/65535.0;   -- should this happen lice this or in architecture?
    nr3 <= REAL(CONV_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(in3)))/65535.0;
    nr4 <= REAL(CONV_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(in4)))/65535.0;
    nr5 <= REAL(CONV_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(in5)))/65535.0;
    nr6 <= REAL(CONV_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(in6)))/65535.0;
    nr7 <= REAL(CONV_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(in7)))/65535.0;
    nr8 <= REAL(CONV_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(in8)))/65535.0;   
    end process;

ifstatement:   -- definetly the shortest and easiest to understand coding way, thank you user1155120, THIS HERE WAS MADE THE WRONG WAY TO SHOW MY PROBLEM :) 
    process (nr1, nr2, nr3, nr4, nr5, nr6, nr7, nr8, a, b, c, d, e, f)
    begin
        if a <= b then
            var1 <= nr1;
            var2 <= nr2;
        elsif c <= d then
            var1 <= nr3;
            var2 <= nr4;
            var3 <= nr5;
        elsif e <= f then
            var2 <= nr6;
            var3 <= nr7;
        else 
            var3 <= nr8;
        end if;
    end process;


MONITOR_IF:
    process (if_result)
    begin
        report "if_result1 = " & to_string(var1);
        report "if_result2 = " & to_string(var2);
        report "if_result3 = " & to_string(var3);
    end process;

    out1 <= var1;
    out1 <= var1;
    out1 <= var1;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ifcase_tb is   -- the testbench
end entity;

architecture foo of ifcase_tb is
    --default in values: random numbers, just to show
    signal in1:   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := "0000000000000001";
    signal in2:   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := "0000000000000100"; 
    signal in3:   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := "0000000000010000";
    signal in4:   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := "0000000010000000";
    signal in5:   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := "0000000100000000";
    signal in6:   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := "0000100000000000"; 
    signal in7:   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := "0001000000000000";
    signal in8:   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := "1000000000000000";

    -- I don't get this one, why all bits to 1 or 0?
    signal a:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '1');
    signal b:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal c:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '1');
    signal d:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal e:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '1');
    signal f:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    signal out1: std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    signal out2: std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    signal out3: std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);

    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;

begin

DUT:
    entity work.ifcase
        port map (
            in1 => in1,
            in2 => in2,
            in3 => in3,
            in4 => in4,
            in5 => in5,
            in6 => in6,
            in7 => in7,
            in8 => in8,
            a => a,
            b => b,
            c => c,
            d => d,
            e => e,
            f => f,
            result => result
        );

STIMULIS:
    process                     -- is this made to synchronize the signals or just to show delay functionality?
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        a <= (others => '0');  -- now equal gives seq1
        wait for 10 ns;
        a <= (others => '1');  -- undo
        c <= (others => '0');  -- now equal gives seq2
        wait for 10 ns;
        c <= (others => '1');  -- undo
        e <= (others => '0');  -- now equal gives seq3
        wait for 10 ns;
        e <= (others => '1');  -- undo
        wait for 10 ns;        -- displays seq4 again
        wait;
    end process;

 MONTIOR:
 process (result)
 begin
     report "result = " & to_string(result);
 end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Consider a better understanding of VHDL might  eliminate your questions. The 1st code frag is missing a sensitivity clause and doesn't 'look' like the linked image (no correlation with vars, nrs and seqs nor is the output named, elsifs, thens). The 2nd doesn't contain valid  case statement syntax (the idea of producing SEL is valid). There are no delays apparent in your code see IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement for VHDL's delay models. Delta cycles do not consume simulation time.

Comment: *To eliminate the delay...* What delay?

Comment: Your question could be improved a lot. 1) The main question should be on the title. 2) The sub-questions should be numbered consequently. 3) You should have given a valid code sample because your question is about synthesis. 4) Your are talking about a _delay of 1_ and so. Please specify the times unit: delta cycles, clock cycles, or (nano, pico, ...) seconds.

Comment: @MartinZabel Ok, I will fix all that. Thanks for the advise!

Comment: What is meant by `seq1`, `seq2`, and `seq3` in process `C1`  in the second example?

Comment: I edited it. Now only the Pictures contain "seq.." for easy understanding. It made the code temporarily more wrong but im working on an inclusion of @user1155120 's code for even better understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement process V1 doesn't match your first image:

[image: first image]

Your VHDL code in both cases isn't quite valid. The case statement comes close to the second image:

[image: second image]

A case statement can be represented by an if then-else if then -else statement structure with a couple of caveats. Only one choice is executed (elsif) and all the values being evaluated belong to the same subtype, which is where you found you could use SEL as the evaluated expression.

It's possible to write your if statement to match the first image, and case statement to match the second image:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ifcase is
    port (
        seq1:   in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0); -- a token size
        seq2:   in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0); 
        seq3:   in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        seq4:   in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        a:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);   -- also arbitrary size
        b:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        c:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        d:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        e:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        f:      in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        result: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of ifcase is

    signal if_result:       std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal case_result:     std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal case2_result:    std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal a_lteq_b:        bit;
    signal c_lteq_d:        bit;
    signal e_lteq_f:        bit;

    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;

begin

ifstatement:   -- This matchs your image block diagram
    process (seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4, a, b, c, d, e, f)
    begin
        if a <= b then
            if_result <= seq1;
        elsif c <= d then
            if_result <= seq2;
        elsif e <= f then
            if_result <= seq3;
        else 
            if_result <= seq4;
        end if;
    end process;

casestatement:  -- This should match the above if statement
    process (seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4, a, b, c, d, e, f)
        variable sel:   bit_vector (1 downto 0);  -- no others choice
    begin
        if a <= b then       -- notice this matches ifstatement
            sel := "00";
        elsif  c <= d then
            sel := "01";
        elsif e <= f then
            sel := "10";
        else 
            sel := "11";
        end if;
        case sel is
            when "00" =>
                case_result <= seq1;
            when "01" =>
                case_result <= seq2;
            when "10" =>
                case_result <= seq3;
            when "11" =>
                case_result <= seq4;  -- all bit values of sel shown
        end case;                     -- no others choice required
    end process;

    a_lteq_b <= '1' when a <= b else
                '0';
    c_lteq_d <= '1' when c <= d else
                '0';
    e_lteq_f <= '1' when e <= f else
                '0';    

case2statement:  -- This should matches the second image
    process (seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4, a_lteq_b, c_lteq_d, e_lteq_f)
        variable sel:   bit_vector (2 downto 0);
    begin
        sel := a_lteq_b & c_lteq_d & e_lteq_f; 
        case sel is
            when "100" | "101" | "110" | "111" =>
                case2_result <= seq1;
            when "010" | "011" =>
                case2_result <= seq2;
            when "001" =>
                case2_result <= seq3;
            when "000" =>
                case2_result <= seq4; 
        end case; 
    end process;

MONITOR_IF:
    process (if_result)
    begin
        report "if_result = " & to_string(if_result);
    end process;

MONITOR_CASE:
    process (case_result)
    begin
        report "case_result = " & to_string(case_result);
    end process;

MONITOR_CASE2:
    process (case2_result)
    begin
        report "case2_result = " & to_string(case2_result);
    end process;

    result <= if_result;  -- pick one

end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ifcase_tb is   -- the testbench
end entity;

architecture foo of ifcase_tb is
    signal seq1:   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0001";
    signal seq2:   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0010"; 
    signal seq3:   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0011";
    signal seq4:   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0100";
    signal a:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '1');
    signal b:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal c:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '1');
    signal d:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal e:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '1');
    signal f:      unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    -- for default a,b,c,d,e,f the default result should be seq4
    signal result: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;

begin

DUT:
    entity work.ifcase
        port map (
            seq1 => seq1,
            seq2 => seq2,
            seq3 => seq3,
            seq4 => seq4,
            a => a,
            b => b,
            c => c,
            d => d,
            e => e,
            f => f,
            result => result
        );

STIMULIS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        a <= (others => '0');  -- now equal gives seq1
        wait for 10 ns;
        a <= (others => '1');  -- undo
        c <= (others => '0');  -- now equal gives seq2
        wait for 10 ns;
        c <= (others => '1');  -- undo
        e <= (others => '0');  -- now equal gives seq3
        wait for 10 ns;
        e <= (others => '1');  -- undo
        wait for 10 ns;        -- displays seq4 again
        wait;
    end process;

 MONTIOR:
 process (result)
 begin
     report "result = " & to_string(result);
 end process;
end architecture;
```

And the testbench gives:

> ifcase.vhdl:108:9:@0ms:(report note): if_result = UUUU
>   ifcase.vhdl:114:9:@0ms:(report note): case_result = UUUU
>   ifcase.vhdl:120:9:@0ms:(report note): case2_result = UUUU
>   ifcase.vhdl:196:6:@0ms:(report note): result = UUUU
>   ifcase.vhdl:120:9:@0ms:(report note): case2_result = 0100
>   ifcase.vhdl:114:9:@0ms:(report note): case_result = 0100
>   ifcase.vhdl:108:9:@0ms:(report note): if_result = 0100
>   ifcase.vhdl:196:6:@0ms:(report note): result = 0100
>   ifcase.vhdl:108:9:@10ns:(report note): if_result = 0001
>   ifcase.vhdl:114:9:@10ns:(report note): case_result = 0001
>   ifcase.vhdl:120:9:@10ns:(report note): case2_result = 0001
>   ifcase.vhdl:196:6:@10ns:(report note): result = 0001
>   ifcase.vhdl:108:9:@20ns:(report note): if_result = 0010
>   ifcase.vhdl:114:9:@20ns:(report note): case_result = 0010
>   ifcase.vhdl:196:6:@20ns:(report note): result = 0010
>   ifcase.vhdl:120:9:@20ns:(report note): case2_result = 0010
>   ifcase.vhdl:108:9:@30ns:(report note): if_result = 0011
>   ifcase.vhdl:114:9:@30ns:(report note): case_result = 0011
>   ifcase.vhdl:196:6:@30ns:(report note): result = 0011
>   ifcase.vhdl:120:9:@30ns:(report note): case2_result = 0011
>   ifcase.vhdl:108:9:@40ns:(report note): if_result = 0100
>   ifcase.vhdl:114:9:@40ns:(report note): case_result = 0100
>   ifcase.vhdl:120:9:@40ns:(report note): case2_result = 0100
>   ifcase.vhdl:196:6:@40ns:(report note): result = 0100

Note the first eight are at simulation time 0 (the default reporting unit is ms).  The four with "UUUU" are initial events on if_result, case_result, case2_result and result. Once the intial values from the testbench propagate through the model the output goes to "0100" which is seq4 (all four have distinct default values). That occurs because the values on a - f produce all false comparisons for a <= b, c <= d, e <= f.

So the test bench first makes one comparison then another, then the last in order true, then returns to all false.  And that gives in order ever (because of the delay introduced with wait statements in the testbenches STIMULIS process) seq1, seq2, seq3 then seq4 again.

You can see the order of the report statements changes after the first four, that's due to a different number of delta cycles. In any event the order concurrent processes execute isn't guaranteed in VHDL.

Note I slipped a smaller case statement in the middle showing a two bit SEL.

All three of the processes in ifcase produced equivalent results, and should provide equivalent results when synthesized.  Which one is easier to read?

There's also an equivalent conditional signal assignment statement which when used as a concurrent statement produces the equivalent process to process if_statement:

```
if_result <= seq1 when a <= b else
             seq2 when c <= d else
             seq3 when e <= f else
             seq4;
```

And this is harder to mess up, not needing a sensitivity list (although the 2008 revision of the standard introduces `all` to represent all signals appearing on the right hand side of a signal assignment).

Your questions:
**1: Does the multiple statement thing work? Since I think I know how mux' work, I wonder, if it's possible to punch multiple commands through one.**

The original [How to convert multiple if else in SWITCH case [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740826/how-to-convert-multiple-if-else-in-switch-case) shows an if statement with elseif's.

An if then elsif is a priority encoder. Independent if statements don't work the same.

**2: Does the "ignoring" of some variables (seq1 i.e. ignores var3) create "latch behavior"? I want to keep the old values in that variable and I think this way that should happen.**

Yes it would create latches. They are generally undesirable. An FPGA vendor would publish guidelines how to infer latches by RTL constructs, derived from IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (now withdrawn).

Your "sub questions":

**1: is there a way to directly use <= ? because it's used as the "write to" command I tried to workaround by "if then else". Any simpler way?**

Note in the two case processes in the code I wrote there are signals and some variables. The variable use can overcome waiting on signal update (which won't occur in the current simulation cycle, but may occur at the current simulation time - for a delta cycle).

You can also break things into smaller pieces. Note the assignments to the three signals a_lteq_b, c_lteq_d and e_lteq_f.

**2: Do I have to add a sort of delay? Since the first stage is a <= Operator a delay of 1 will be created**

No. You can but it's possible to write VHDL so you don't have to. The secret is not to depend on a value on a signal in the same simulation cycle (the same traversal of a process) in which it is assigned. Sometimes (as shown) you can do that by using variables, who's value is available immediately.

VHDL has statements not commands, either sequential (executed in order) or concurrent (executed in parallel, the order not guaranteed). Every concurrent statement is elaborated into one or more processes possibly contained within block statements representing hierarchy. Subprograms are either functions or procedures. Function calls are expressions (contained within statements) while procedure calls are statements.

A process is an independent sequence of statements that suspends through encountering explicit or implicit wait statements and resumes when a condition dependent on a signal it is sensitive to becomes true (e.g. an event on a signal in the sensitivity list, also see IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.2 Wait statement).

Comment: Awesome! I did not expect to get such precise and extensive answer so fast! especially since you posted a complete working script.

It shows my thinking mistakes and backs up most of my thoughts.

Comment: However, you misunderstood some of my sample code/commenting. I edited it now for better understanding. seq1,seq2,seq3 and seq4 aren't signals. They are a placeholder for the code lines in the first sample, because I don't know how to implement that into the "case...is". That was basically my question. If it's possible to do that in some way.

Basically you answered that indirectly by your code sample, since you never use multiple Statements.

Thank you!

Comment: I incorporated Your code on the bottom of the question. Can you now see my problem? Thanks again for your answer, helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your `V1` process is not correct:

- there is a missing `then` after each condition
- VHDL has a true *else if* statement in contrast to C. In C it's emulated by writing `else` and `if` into the same line. Then *else if* keyword is `elsif`.

So here is the fixed `V1` process:

```
V1 : process
begin
  if (a<=b) then        -- seq1
    var1 <= nr1;
    var2 <= nr2;
  elsif (c<=d) then     -- seq2
    var1 <= nr3;
    var2 <= nr4;
    var3 <= nr5;
  elsif (d<=f) then    -- seq3
    var2 <= nr6;
    var3 <= nr7;
  else           -- seq4
    var3 <= nr8;
  end if;
end process V1;
```

To question 2:
Yes it will infere a latch. That's not a good design choice unless you really know what you are doing!

Saving states should be done by registers.

Your second example code generates multiple drivers on `sel`. It like creating short circuits!

To question 4:
Signal assignments have no delay unless you specify for example an explicit delay:

```
y <= transport x after 10 ns;
```

A variable like `sel` cannot be declared outside a process, unless it's a shared variable. The rule of thumb for shared variables is as for latches: use it only if you know what you are doing ;).